# How to use column names stored in Array with PLSQL Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following PL/SQL code:

```
DECLARE 
CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT last_name, job_id 
    FROM employees
    WHERE job_id LIKE '%CLERK%' AND manager_id > 120
    ORDER BY last_name;
BEGIN
  FOR item IN c1 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
      ('Name = ' || item.last_name || ', Job = ' || item.job_id);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Now, suppose I have the column names in a varray named Test of varchar type. That is, Test(1) has last_name, Test(2) has job_id. How to use the above loop in that case ?
item.Test(i) is not working.

Comment: I would just use a normal nested table type rather than a `varray`, unless the specific size you are going to set it to is overwhelmingly useful. In general varrays aren't that useful in PL/SQL.

Comment: I want to display the result of a dynamic Select query that can be different every time in a tabular format. The query is coming from a lookup. 
I asked the question because I was able to do it if the columns were static. So for the case when the columns were changing, I was taking the column names first in an array, but then I was not sure how to use the Array indexes inside the cursor while using 'CursorName.Array(i)' ; where Array(i) has my column name.

Comment: If you are using Oracle 12c,  You can use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` for such purposes. Prior to 12c, you may need to write a few more lines of code : Refer the links -  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS00001

Comment: @KaushikNayak DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT works. Can you also help me with how can I include the result set fetched by it in the mail body ?

Comment: @Now, where did the mail body come from?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Now I have to mail the results. So they have to be included in the mail body :D

Comment: What you want now is not related to this question and thus not in the scope of this comment section. Either google it or ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the simplest case, where you have always two columns and the data type is always the same.

```
DECLARE 
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    n VARCHAR2(100),
    id NUMBER

CURSOR c1 IS
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR
    'SELECT '||test(1)||','||test(2)|| 
    ' FROM employees '||
    ' WHERE job_id LIKE :job AND manager_id > :m '||
    ' ORDER BY '||test(1) USING '%CLERK%', 120;

    LOOP
       FETCH cur INTO n, id;
       EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
      ('Name = ' || n || ', Job = ' || id);

    END LOOP;
END;
```

In case the number of columns and data type is not know at design time it will be a bit more complex, however you did not tell us your requirements.